# Prove that if $ a|b$ and $b|a$, then $a=b$ or $a=-b$

Tags: number-theory

I'm having difficulty proving that if $a|b$ and $b|a$, then $a=b$ or $a=-b$. Logically, it makes sense to me, but I don't know how to express it.

Answer (score 9):

Assume $ab \neq 0$. If $a\mid b$ then $b = na$, and $b\mid a$ then $a = mb$, thus: $ab = mnab \to mn = 1 \to m = n = 1$ or $m = n = -1$.

Comment: You may need to consider the special case "$a=0$ or $b=0$", no?

Comment: If $a = 0$ or $b = 0$, then $a = b = 0$.

Comment: If $a=0$ WLOG, then we have a division error in $a|b$. Is $0$ a factor of any integer?

Comment: $0 = 2\times 0$